# Найти параболу по двум точкам

Tags: физика

Первая точка, из которой вылетает объект, вторая куда он приземляется (точки на разной высоте(y)).
Понятно, что чисто математически таких парабол может быть бесконечно много. Но зная  начальную скорость объекта, мы можем найти его конкретную траекторию.
Пожалуйста, подскажите как!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот есть 2 полезные ссылки по этой теме ([первая](https://ido.tsu.ru/schools/physmat/data/res/virtlab/text/m2_1.html) и [вторая](http://tm.spbstu.ru/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0,_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BA_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83))

Если я все правильно понял, то формула параболы будет выглядеть так 
[image: формула параболы]

подставив значение первой и второй точек можно получить формулу для α
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно